# Flutter - RaisedButton onPressed with Multiple Condition

Tags: flutter

Just move to flutter and little bit frustration about multiple condition in raisedbutton onpressed.

I have bool `buttonDisabled1` and bool `buttonDisabled2`. I want `if buttonDisabled1 == true AND buttonDisabled2 == true` (both of them == true), so `onPressed = null`, it works.

However, if `buttonDisabled1 or buttonDisabled2 == false` (ONE of them is false) `onPressed` not null anymore.

My goal is :

```
buttonDisabled1 == true AND buttonDisabled2 == true -> onpressed null;
buttonDisabled1 == false AND buttonDisabled2 == true -> onpressed null; 
buttonDisabled1 == true AND buttonDisabled2 == false -> onpressed null; 
buttonDisabled1 == false AND buttonDisabled2 == false -> onpressed not null;
```

Thanks in advice :)

Below my code, none of them works.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  bool buttonDisabled1 = true;
  bool buttonDisabled2 = true;

RaisedButton(
  child: Text('Click'),
  onPressed: buttonDisabled1 && buttonDisabled2 ? null : (){},
),
}
```

```dart
RaisedButton(
  child: Text('Click'),
  onPressed: (buttonDisabled1 && buttonDisabled2) ? null : (){},
),
```

```dart
RaisedButton(
  child: Text('Click'),
  onPressed: ((buttonDisabled1) && (buttonDisabled2)) ? null : (){},
),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RaisedButton(
  child: Text('Click'),
  onPressed: !buttonDisabled1 && !buttonDisabled2 ? (){} : null,
),
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. IT WORKS..thank you very much Sir...
buttonDisabled1 = true
, so..
!buttonDisabled1 = false?